# Provide csrf _token in headers when using Laravel API

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

How can I create a Laravel Gate where client has to provide CSRF _token in headers when when using my api?

Idea is that I want somekind of gate when using my route:
http://127.0.0.1:50004/api/third-party/unsplash

Otherwise, anyone can copy and use above route.

**api.php**

```php
Route::get('/third-party/unsplash', [UnsplashController::class, 'show'])
    **// my gate here!!!!**
```

**UnsplashController.php**

```php
 public function show()
    {
        return ['authorizationKey' => 'Client-ID 1234'];
    }
```

**Unsplash.vue file:**

```js
const myAsync = async function fetchUnsplash() {
  const myAPIKey = await fetch(
    'http://127.0.0.1:50004/api/third-party/unsplash'
  );

  const dataMyAPIKey = await myAPIKey.json();

  const response = await fetch('https://api.unsplash.com', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: dataMyAPIKey,
    },
  });

  console.log(response);
};
```

Comment: Do you want to protect your api routes?

Comment: Yes. I want to protect my api routes.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on a CSRF token, you probably want full API authentication with something like [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum). Implementing Sanctum will help you protect your API effectively (including [from CSRF attacks](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#csrf-protection)).

If you *really do* want to require a CSRF token in the header, you can implement that by adding custom [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware) to those routes that would check for the CSRF token. You can look at the `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware as a starting point. Typically, the `X-CSRF-TOKEN` header is used to pass the CSRF token in a request.

Finally, you could potentially just use the built-in `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware if you choose to convert your `/third-party/unsplash` route from a `GET` to a `POST`.

All-in-all, I think using a more robust solution like Sanctum will serve you well and prevent other potential issues that you might not have thought of yet.